# Is there something of CANVAS shadow properties like the "spread" property of CSS box-shadow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

For CSS box-shadow, the "spread" property is used to set the size of shadow. But the shadow API of CANVAS seems lack of the counterpart property.

I know the answer is probably NO.

But is there some way to achieve the shadow "spread" effect on CANVAS?

If the answer is still NO, will it be "YES" in the next up-coming HTML standard?

Comment: When browsers will support the 5 params version of `filter: drop-shadow()` we will be able to have it quite easily. For the time being I guess the best we can get is through SVG filters, but even feDropShadow doesn't have such a *spread* option. With some shapes we can do something, using transforms but it's really convoluted and since shadows are not directly affected by the canvas transforms, it requires knowing the center of the shape to be drawn which is sometimes impossible (with transparent images for instance). Here is my little playground: https://jsfiddle.net/sx084zvg/

Comment: Thank you, Kaiido. I have learned a lot from your code.

Answer (score 3):

> But is there some way to achieve the shadow "spread" effect on CANVAS?

Yup :)

### How ?

A way to mimic the `spread radius` is to create a bigger version of the box that we will position outside the canvas & use the offset X and offset Y to get its shadow inside the canvas at the place we want. It will only remain to draw the original box after that.

---

### Explanation :

To create a bigger box we will use [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale), we will need to calculate the scale factor first.
[image]

We obtain the scale factor (SF) by doing the ratio between the size of the wanted shadow and the size of the box `SF = (boxW + 2 * spreadRadius) / boxW`

Then we will save the entire state of the canvas with the [save()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) method before calling the scale(), so we will be able to get back our original state after the manipulation (with the [restore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) method)

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const w = canvas.width;
const h = canvas.height;

const x = 50;
let y = 20;
const spreadRadius = 10;
const boxW = 50;
const boxH = 50;
const color = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)';
const blurRadius = 10;
const offsetX = 0;
const offsetY = 0;

ctx.fillRect(x, y, boxW, boxH);
ctx.font = "16px Arial";
ctx.fillText('Origin Box', x + 100, y + 30);

ctx.save();
y += 85;
let scaleFactor = ((2 * spreadRadius) + boxW) / boxW;
ctx.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
ctx.fillRect((x - spreadRadius) / scaleFactor, (y - spreadRadius ) / scaleFactor, boxW, boxH);
ctx.restore();
ctx.fillText('Scaled Box', x + 100, y + 30);

ctx.save();
y += 100;
scaleFactor = ((2 * spreadRadius) + boxW) / boxW;
ctx.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
ctx.shadowColor = color;
ctx.shadowBlur = blurRadius;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = offsetX;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = offsetY;
ctx.fillRect((x - spreadRadius) / scaleFactor, (y - spreadRadius) / scaleFactor, boxW, boxH);
ctx.restore();
ctx.fillText('Scaled Box with shadow', x + 100, y + 30);

ctx.save();
y += 100;
scaleFactor = ((2 * spreadRadius) + boxW) / boxW;
ctx.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
ctx.shadowColor = color;
ctx.shadowBlur = blurRadius;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = offsetX + w;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = offsetY + h;
ctx.fillRect((x - spreadRadius - w) / scaleFactor, (y - spreadRadius - h) / scaleFactor, boxW, boxH);
ctx.restore();
ctx.fillText('Same but we draw the box outside the canvas', x + 100, y + 30);
ctx.fillText('and keep its shadow by playing on the offsets', x + 100, y + 47);

ctx.save();
y += 100;
scaleFactor = ((2 * spreadRadius) + boxW) / boxW;
ctx.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
ctx.shadowColor = color;
ctx.shadowBlur = blurRadius;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = offsetX + w;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = offsetY + h;
ctx.fillRect((x - spreadRadius - w) / scaleFactor, (y - spreadRadius - h) / scaleFactor, boxW, boxH);
ctx.restore();
ctx.clearRect(x, y, boxW, boxH);
ctx.fillRect(x, y, boxW, boxH);
ctx.fillText('Origin Box + shadow with the spread radius', x + 100, y + 30);
```

```css
#canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

The trick is to draw the scaled box outside the canvas. We're doing so by substracting the width & height of the canvas to the x & y position of the scaled box. By doing so, we are sure that it's drawn outside the canvas:

```
ctx.fillRect(x - w, y - h, boxW, boxH); // We substract w to the x position and h to the y position
```

And then, we add it to the shadow offsets to draw the shadow inside the canvas:

```
ctx.shadowOffsetX = offsetX + w; // We add w which is the canvas width
ctx.shadowOffsetY = offsetY + h; // We add h which is the canvas height
```

Only remain to draw the original box and we have our desired result.

---

### Function

I created a `boxShadow()` function to gather all the approach in a concret example. That function work like that:

1. Create a shadowValues Object:

   ```
   const newShadowObject = {box: {posX: x, posY: y, width: boxW, height: boxH}, offsetX, offsetY, blurRadius, spreadRadius, color}
   ```
2. Call the `boxShadow()` function with the object as parameter:

   ```
   boxShadow(newShadowObject);
   ```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const w = canvas.width;
const h = canvas.height;

function boxShadow(shadowValues){

  const {box: {posX: x, posY: y, width: boxW, height: boxH}, offsetX, offsetY, blurRadius, spreadRadius, color} = shadowValues;
  
    // We draw the shadow
    ctx.save();
    const scaleFactor = ((2 * spreadRadius) + boxW) / boxW;
    ctx.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    ctx.shadowColor = color;
    ctx.shadowBlur = blurRadius;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = offsetX + w;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = offsetY + h;  
    ctx.fillRect((x - spreadRadius - w) / scaleFactor, (y - spreadRadius - h) / scaleFactor, boxW, boxH);
    ctx.restore();
    // We draw the original box
    ctx.clearRect(x, y, boxW, boxH);
    ctx.rect(x, y, boxW, boxH);
    ctx.stroke();
    
}

const case1 = {box: {posX: 30, posY: 30, width: 50, height: 50}, offsetX: 0, offsetY: 0, blurRadius: 0, spreadRadius: 0, color: '#ff0000'};
boxShadow(case1);
ctx.font = "16px Arial";
ctx.fillText("offsetX: 0", 30, 120);
ctx.fillText("offsetY: 0", 30, 140);
ctx.fillText("blurRadius: 0", 30, 160);
ctx.fillText("spreadRadius: 0", 30, 180);

const case2 = {box: {posX: 170, posY: 30, width: 50, height: 50}, offsetX: 0, offsetY: 0, blurRadius: 0, spreadRadius: 10, color: '#ff0000'};
boxShadow(case2);
ctx.font = "16px Arial";
ctx.fillText("offsetX: 0", 170, 120);
ctx.fillText("offsetY: 0", 170, 140);
ctx.fillText("blurRadius: 0", 170, 160);
ctx.fillText("spreadRadius: 10", 170, 180);

const case3 = {box: {posX: 320, posY: 30, width: 50, height: 50}, offsetX: 5, offsetY: 5, blurRadius: 0, spreadRadius: 10, color: '#ff0000'};
boxShadow(case3);
ctx.font = "16px Arial";
ctx.fillText("offsetX: 5", 320, 120);
ctx.fillText("offsetY: 5", 320, 140);
ctx.fillText("blurRadius: 0", 320, 160);
ctx.fillText("spreadRadius: 10", 320, 180);

const case4 = {box: {posX: 470, posY: 30, width: 50, height: 50}, offsetX: 5, offsetY: 5, blurRadius: 20, spreadRadius: 10, color: '#ff0000'};
boxShadow(case4);
ctx.font = "16px Arial";
ctx.fillText("offsetX: 5", 470, 120);
ctx.fillText("offsetY: 5", 470, 140);
ctx.fillText("blurRadius: 20", 470, 160);
ctx.fillText("spreadRadius: 10", 470, 180);

const case5 = {box: {posX: 55, posY: 225, width: 50, height: 100}, offsetX: 0, offsetY: 0, blurRadius: 20, spreadRadius: 0, color: '#ff0000'};
boxShadow(case5);
ctx.font = "16px Arial";
ctx.fillText("offsetX: 0", 30, 380);
ctx.fillText("offsetY: 0", 30, 400);
ctx.fillText("blurRadius: 20", 30, 420);
ctx.fillText("spreadRadius: 0", 30, 440);

const case6 = {box: {posX: 200, posY: 250, width: 100, height: 50}, offsetX: 10, offsetY: 5, blurRadius: 0, spreadRadius: 0, color: '#ff0000'};
boxShadow(case6);
ctx.font = "16px Arial";
ctx.fillText("offsetX: 10", 200, 380);
ctx.fillText("offsetY: 5", 200, 400);
ctx.fillText("blurRadius: 0", 200, 420);
ctx.fillText("spreadRadius: 0", 200, 440);

const case7 = {box: {posX: 400, posY: 210, width: 50, height: 50}, offsetX: 70, offsetY: 70, blurRadius: 10, spreadRadius: 10, color: '#ff0000'};
boxShadow(case7);
ctx.font = "16px Arial";
ctx.fillText("offsetX: 70", 400, 380);
ctx.fillText("offsetY: 70", 400, 400);
ctx.fillText("blurRadius: 0", 400, 420);
ctx.fillText("spreadRadius: 10", 400, 440);
```

```css
#canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #EFEFFA;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="620" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: As I said in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60656468/is-there-something-of-canvas-shadow-properties-like-the-spread-property-of-css#comment107329648_60656468) on the question, this only works with some primitive shapes. You need to know at least the size of what you're gonna draw and where its center is. And this is impossible with for instance png images. You could very well have some pixels on the top left corner and some others on the bottom right corner, that *hack* would make it off. https://jsfiddle.net/2dte6cx3/

Comment: @Kaiido Although this might be right (I can't tell, I didn't explored enough with images to have an informed opinion about it), this answer the question. It was asked like "the spread of the CSS box-shadow property", property which adds shadow effects around an element's frame, which is always a box. It was NOT stated anything about image, nor drop-shadow(). But the added precision is nice, and indeed, when `filter: drop-shadow()` will have this support, the shadow on image will be convenient.

Comment: I fear you misread the question then. They are not trying to mimic the CSS box-shadow behavior but are wondering if there is *something of CANVAS shadow properties like the “spread” property of CSS box-shadow?*. In other words, they only want the *"spread"* operation from the box-shadow to apply on the 2D context's shadow. That is, it should apply to any drawings, bitmaps included. And also box shadow is able to handle more complex shapes than just rects: https://jsfiddle.net/k35r2d0x/

Comment: He did NOT say the “spread” parameter of drop-shadow() CSS function. The autor didn't make any precision about what use he wanted to do with it, that was your interpretation, mine differs from yours :)
And for your jsfidle example "more complex shapes than just rects", right... I NEVER say the opposite, I said "box", and even if you attach a class called circle with which you add some border-radius, that's still a box.

Comment: And your code doesn't handle that. So even under your weird interpretation, your answer is not complete. Also nobody talked about drop-shadows apart from my very first comment where I pointed out the *should-be* solution. Finally, they clearly are asking to spread the canvas shadow, not much room for interpretation here.

Comment: How come ? Please, feel free to give me a box which won't get its shadow through this function. I may have missed something and I'll be glad to figure out to see if I can work it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210136/discussion-between-wax-and-kaiido).

Comment: From the end of discussion, like it's somehow deleted, will post it in there if someone lookout for a way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/8d1rqzct/  This cover boxes with radius. -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- But it would need adaptation (like working on several canvas) because it uses a function who `tightestBoxContainingPath()` which need to calcul on all the canvas. Check the box to see a comparaison with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do this.

There is a hope someday [`drop-shadow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) CSS function will support that parameter too, that day we will be able to use it in the `filter` parameter of our 2D contexts, but for the time being the closest we can have is through SVG filters.

Here is one attempt of mine, which only approximates what `box-shadow`'s do. Nevertheless, it may help:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

const filter = spreadingBoxShadow( 5, 5, 5, 15, 'lime' );
const img = new Image();
img.onload = (e) => {
  ctx.filter = filter;
  ctx.drawImage( img, 50, 50, 200, 150 );
};
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";


function spreadingBoxShadow( offset_x, offset_y, blur_radius, spread_radius, color ) {

  const _id = "spread-radius-" + Date.now();
  const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
  svg.classList.add( 'hidden-svg' );
  svg.innerHTML = `
    <filter id="${ _id }" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-color="${ color }" result="flood" in="SourceAlpha" />
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" in="flood" operator="atop" result="color" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="${ spread_radius}" result="spread" in="color"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="spread" stdDeviation="${ blur_radius }" result="shadow"/>
    <feOffset dx="${ offset_x }" dy="${ offset_y }" in="shadow" result="offset"/>
      <feMerge result="merge">
        <feMergeNode in="offset"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
`;
  document.body.append( svg );
  return `url(#${ _id })`;

}
```

```css
.hidden-svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```